# Routing trouble for logout link? DELETE vs GET action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Right now the route for my logout link points to sessions#destroy, but it isn't the HTTP delete verb, so it isn't working.  This problem is frustrating me because I should be able to figure it out myself, but I've had no luck so far.  Here is the error message I get when trying to log out:

No route matches [DELETE] "/logout"

Here is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do



  get 'line_items/create'



  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'testimonials' => 'static_pages#testimonials'
  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :products
  resources :categories
  resources :line_items
  resources :carts
 end
```

The destroy method in the sessions controller:

```
def destroy
  forget(current_user)
  session.delete(:user_id)
  @current_user = nil
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

The logout link:

```
          <li>
            <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
          </li>
```

relevant results of rake routes:

```
logout_path     GET     /logout(.:format)   sessions#destroy
users_path  GET     /users(.:format)    users#index
POST    /users(.:format)    users#create
new_user_path   GET     /users/new(.:format)    users#new
edit_user_path  GET     /users/:id/edit(.:format)   users#edit
user_path   GET     /users/:id(.:format)    users#show
PATCH   /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
PUT     /users/:id(.:format)    users#update
DELETE  /users/:id(.:format)    users#destroy
sessions_path   POST    /sessions(.:format)     sessions#create
new_session_path    GET     /sessions/new(.:format)     sessions#new
session_path    DELETE  /sessions/:id(.:format)     sessions#destroy
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: post the o/p of $rake routes | grep logout you are missing the delete method, it should not be get

Comment: Just posted results of rake routes, yes I know I just don't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Change the link to use the defined route

   ```
   <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path %>
   ```

   or

   ```
   <%= link_to "Log out", session_path, method: "delete" %>
   ```

   Please note that in order for the last link to work, you need to change it into a singular resource (resource, not resources).

   ```
   resource :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
   ```
2. Change the route from

   ```
   get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
   ```

   to

   ```
   delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
   ```

In any case, the plural `resources` on sessions does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

add `match '/logout', to: 'session#destroy', via: 'delete'` to your routes.rb file

execute `rake routes` to check the routes supported by your application.

Comment: gets this error message: /config/routes.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' match 'logout', to: 'session#destroy', via :delete ^

Comment: i have updated the code, there was syntax error in the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes.rb file, you are setting the verb for logout to get:

```
get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
```

You need to set it to delete:

```
delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since rails 7 (at least), it is possible to create a link that perform a request with method DELETE on click.

Add attribut `data-turbo-method='delete'` to the link.

E.g.:

```
= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, data: { turbo_method: :delete }
```

Answer (score 0):

As of rails 7, you may need to do something like this

`<%= link_to "logout", destroy_user_session_path, data: { turbo_method: :delete } %>`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your contribution, however there is already the same code posted by Constantin De La Roche. Have you considered upvote or comment on their answer instead of posting your own? (also you have a syntax error there at `:delete"`)

Comment: Oh I see, didn't noticed. However you're correct that there is a syntax mistake and that is quotation. my bad